# acts_as_taggable_on allowing one tagging per (tagger_id , taggable_id) pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have two models: `User` and `Post`

`User acts_as_tagger` and `Post` `acts_as_taggable`

I use the following method to create tagging by a user:

```
@user.tag(@post , :with =>"a tag" , :on => :tags )
```

if I call the method two times with two different tags , the second tags gets the place of the first tag and the first is deleted from the taggings table.

In other words `acts_as_taggable_on` is allowing one row for each pair of `(user_id , post_id)` to be stored in the taggings table. This does not make sense and I was wondering if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out.

tags should be added as a list. If  tags are being added gradually by users, then you first need to retrieve the old tag list , append the new tag to it and then call the tag function to retag the post with all available tags.

If you do it one by one , it assumes that the whole tag list is the entered tag , removes all the old ones and stores the new one.